# Would it be more efficient to have the \n character in the same string literal than to have an extra set of "<<"?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if in code such as this:

```
std::cout << "Hello!" << '\n';
```

Would it be more efficient to have the `\n` character in the same string literal, as in this case, `"Hello!"`? Such as the code would then look like this:

```
std::cout << "Hello!\n";
```

I am aware that things such as these are so miniscule in difference whether one is more efficient than the other (especially in this case), that it just doesn't matter, but it has just been boggling my mind.

**My reasoning:**
If I am not mistaken having the `\n` character in the same string literal would be more efficient, since when you have the extra set of the insertion operator (`operator<<`) you have to call that function once again and whatever is in the implementation of that function, which in this case, in the Standard Library, will happen just for one single character (`\n`). In comparison to only having to do it once, that is, if I were to append that character to the end of the string literal and only have to use one call to `operator<<`.

I guess this is a very simple question but I am not 100% sure about the answer and I love to spend time knowing the details of a language and how little things work better than others.

**Update:**
I am working to find the answer myself as for questions such as this, it is better for one to try and find the answer for themselves, I haven't worked with any Assembly Code in the past, so this will be my firs time trying to.

Comment: Translate your codes to assembler (with optimizations) and compare assemblers. Why do you wish doing it by somebody else?

Comment: That seems plausible. But as always with performance questions: measure it! (A look into the generated code *might* also help.)

Comment: @S.M. I haven't really done anything to do with Assembly code, I am no expert in this field or C++ (yet) for that matter, as I am still learning more and more everyday, but I guess this is my time to try and give it a shot!

Comment: @WernerHenze I will make sure to give it a shot myself and try to look at the generated Assembly code which S.M also suggested, thank you!

Comment: It is true that one is more "efficient" than the other. But how much precious electrons do you really expect to save, on modern, multi-Ghz, multi-core CPUs, one way or another?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand how the question looks from the outside, but I always like to do things the "better way", which could also mean readability, efficiency...etc. Having said that though it is true, that in this case it is just for pure curiosity, I am going to try and deep into the Assembly code now myself, which will save me from asking these very minimalistic questions in the future :p.

Comment: I won't suggest look at assembly, since it can pretty much compiler-(and it's version / flag)-dependent. If you need to check, check the overall performance (I highly doubt this case would be any bottleneck).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the C++ standard does not define how `std::basic_stream<char>` (the type of `std::cout`) has to be implemented which means both overloads of `operator<<` could be implemented as efficiently or as inefficiently as the authors of your compiler like including calling the `operator<<` for every char in the string which would probably result in less efficient code because of the overhead of using a look...

Comment: @appleapple ahh, well I will try and see the Assembly code with optimizations on and off and see, but like you said in this case there probably wouldn't be any difference to really be noticed.

Comment: @fabian something I have to read more about I guess :p

Comment: keep in mind: your code does not describe instructions for the cpu, it rather is an abstract description. If there are 2 equivalent alternative codes and one is generally better than the other then chances are high that the compiler knows about that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yep that is what I was thinking! Also I like your name hehe

Comment: I add language-lawyer tag as this question can be interpret as "can compiler make these 2 code equally efficient"?

Comment: From first principles, I expect the version with a single string literal to be more efficient than the version that makes two calls (e.g. sentry object would need to be constructed twice). I also expect the difference to be immeasurably small, swamped by the cost of actual I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; but all of the ostreams are so inefficient in practice that if you care much about efficiency you shouldn't be using them.

Write code to be clear and maintainable.  Making code faster takes work, and the simpler and clearer your code is the easier to make it faster.

Identify what your bottleneck is, then work on optimizing that by actually working out what is taking time.  (This only fails when global behaviour caused global slowdowns, like fragmentation or messing with caches because).